# ruby: Create block for a string

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I have this object:

```
object.name
```

Sometimes name could be an array, sometimes it could be a string and sometimes an empty string. And so I assumed I could do something like this:

```
object.name do |name|
  name.is_a?(Array) ? name.join(' ') : name
end.presence
```

But this does not work, I can access name in the block but anything I do to it does not return.

What am I actually doing by passing name into a block like that? and how can I make this ruby lovely and work?

Thanks!

Comment: Does your `#name` method takes a block ? First check this .

Comment: Why in your case does `name` have multiple possible types? If you want to accept multiple types to *set* the value, that will mean you will want a different solution than if it *inherently* can hold multiple types of data.

Comment: I can not control what name is and how it is formatted as this is built on top of not so good code.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple way to do this is using the splat operator:

```
name = [ *object.name ].join(' ')
```

If `object.name` is just a string, the code will essentially be doing:

```
name = [ 'some string' ].join(' ')
```

Which will just result in `'some string'`.  However, if `object.name` is an array of strings, you'll end up with:

```
name = [ 'first string', 'second string', 'third string' ].join(' ')
```

Which will result in `'first string second string third string'`.

Comment: Another way to do this is with the `Array()` method: `Array(object.name).join(' ')`

Answer (score 1):

Use a combination of `tap` and `break`.

```
object.name.tap do |name|
  break name.is_a?(Array) ? name.join(' ') : name
end.presence
```